# Extract JSON array using Simple Json Library

Tags: java, json, simplejson

My JSON data look like this.

```
{"Users":[
    {"Username":"Admin1", "Password":"123"},
    {"Username":"Admin2", "Password":"456"},
    {"Username":"Admin3", "Password":"789"}
]}
```

I am trying to extract out all the list of Username and Password.

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./Database/Users.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray userArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Users");
```

How do I then iterate through this JSONArray to achieve what I wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was using org.json.simple, not org.json. And the JSONArray does not have the `int length()` method.

What I did was

```
Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = userArray.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
             JSONObject factObj = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
             String userName = (String) factObj.get("Username");
             String passWord = (String) factObj.get("Password");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadoc ;)

If you are using `org.json.JSONArray`, you can loop using `int length()` to know the array's length and `Object get(index)` or `JSONObject getJSONObject(index)` to get an item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); ++i) {
   JSONObject user = recs.getJSONObject(i);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can probably do something like the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
   JSONObject user = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String username = user.getString("Username");
   String password = user.getString("Password");
   //etc
}
```